# Javascript: RegExp object creation problem

Tags: javascript, validation

I wish to use the following regex for validating a file-upload:

```
/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w ]*))+\.(ext)$/
```

But i want to be able to specify the `ext` filter.

Is this right?

```
function validateFile(str, ext) {
    alert(str);
    var expr = new RegExp("/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w ]*))+\.(" + ext.toLowerCase() + ")$/");
    alert(expr);
    return expr.test(str);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the slashes at the start and end when you use the RegExp constructor:

```
var expr = /foo/;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var expr = new RegExp("foo");
```

You just have to take care of double escaping backslashes (`\`) on the pattern string, for example:

```
var expr = /\\/;
```

Should be:

```
var expr = new RegExp("\\\\");
```

That's because in a string literal, the backslash is used also to escape characters.

**Edit:** The equivalent of

```
var expr = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w ]*))+\.(ext)$/;
```

Should be:

```
var expr = new RegExp("^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\\\{2}\\w+)\\$?)(\\\\(\\w[\\w ]*))+\\.("+
                      ext.toLowerCase + ")$");
```

Note that you can also use the case-insensitive flag, in the literal notation as `/foo/i`, with the `RegExp` constructor: `new RegExp("foo", "i")`.

Comment: ok, after removing the slashes - this is what i have now - `new RegExp("^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\{2}\w+)\$?)(\(\w[\w ]*))+\.(" + ext.toLowerCase() + ")$")`

Comment: @wretrOvian: Give a look to my edit, you need to *double* escape the slashes, not to remove them.