# Javascript regex with literals and single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across this problem when trying to stop a single quote `(')` being matched in a string.

Here is a snippet from a console session in Chrome. Params is the regex I'm trying to match (no single or double quotes should be allowed?). I would have expected the first two execs to find a match and the second two to fail due to the single quote in the text.

Suppose this raises two questions:

1. Why does the literal behave differently to the variable?
2. Why does the third exec find a match when there should be no match on the single quote?

thanks

```
> params
> 
>> "^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_/&,()\[\];:+~.!\\]*$"
> 
> 
> new RegExp(params).exec("some string")
>> ["some string"]
> 
> new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_/&,()\[\];:+~.!\\]*$").exec("some string")
>> null
> 
> 
> new RegExp(params).exec("some string's")
>> ["some string's"]
> 
> new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_/&,()\[\];:+~.!\\]*$").exec("some string's")
>> null
```

Comment: escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154394/javascript-regexp-object-creation-problem

Comment: escape the backslash one more time i.e use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_\/&,()\[\];:+~.!\\]*$/`

Comment: Where does it mention the hyphen in the 'duplicate'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _/&,()[];:+~.!\-]*$
```

Always keep `-` at end or `escape` it to avoid forming an invalid range.

Here `-` forms a range from `space` `32` to `_` `95`.`'` is `39` so it falls in between that invalid range and so a match.